# Remove and add data attributes on navigation

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, attributes, carousel

I wanted to create a Bootstrap carousel on my website with a custom navigation. So I changed the indicators to three blocks with some text and an button in it.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <ul class="slide-nav">
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="col-sm-4 slide-first">
            <div class="nav-element">
                <i class="fa fa-star symbol-big"></i>
                <h3>Leistungen</h3>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Mehr erfahren</a>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1" class="col-sm-4 slide-middle active">
             <div class="nav-element">
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up symbol-big"></i>
                <h3>Ihre Vorteile</h3>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Mehr erfahren</a>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2" class="col-sm-4 slide-last">
             <div class="nav-element">
                <i class="fa fa-users symbol-big"></i>
                <h3>Unser Team</h3>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primaryk">Mehr erfahren</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

The navigation works just fine but when I want to click on a button to access the link it wont work because of the "data-target". If i remove it i can click on the link.

Now I wanted to achieve that when I click on an "li" element with an active class, the "data-attribute" will be removed and when I click on an other it will be added again.

Or is there an even nicer method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did now solve it.

```
$('.slide-nav li').click(function () {
    $(this).removeAttr('data-target');
    $(this).attr('data-target', '#carousel');
    $(".active").attr('data-target', '');
});
```

Only what is maybe missing is that it would be nice if I just could click on the link and get directly on it - not first have to click on the li element to access the link..

Answer (score 0):

Possible Duplicate

you can read and make use of this

[Add & remove active class from a navigation link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379776/add-remove-active-class-from-a-navigation-link)

[sample jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rq9UB/)`enter code here`
[sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
This is not exactly what I was searching. 

The active class is allready given by Bootstrap and is on one of the li elements when the site is loaded. 
At this moment I want the data-target to be removed, now when I click on an other li element the data-target will be added again on the first li and removed on the clicked one.