# set background color when active

Tags: php, html, css

I am making a portfolio website. In the menu I have the follwing itmes:

> Home, Services, Portfolio(dropdown), About me, Contact.

[image: Menu]

Under projects I have to following folder structure:

> Website root -> Portfolio -> projectName.html

When a menu item is active it has a blue background. As it is now, it is only html, so I have assign the correct header, everytime I make a new page there has to be under fx Portfolio. To summary up. I have 5 different headers, where each header have the specific choosen menu blue background attached.

I would like to use 1 header where the function is: If I click on "About me" the "active class" is called, which means the blue background is active. If I click projectName.html under Portfolio the Portfolio menu is active with a blue background.

The only way I know how to make that work is if there exist a user log in, and a session. Can I do something with CSS like this?

```
<!-- begin nav -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span>Tap me!</span>
                        </button>
                        <!-- begin logo in navigation -->
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
                                <img src="images/webdesign_Logo.png">
                        </a>
                        <!-- end logo in navigation -->
                    </div>  

                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-main pull-right">
                            <!-- begin navigation items -->
                            <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="services_smallicon.php">Services</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Portfolio</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="portfolio_2col.php">Portfolio 2 Column</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="portfolio_3col.php">Portfolio 3 Column</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="portfolio_4col.php">Portfolio 4 Column</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="portfolio_single.php">Portfolio Single Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="portfolio_single_fullwidth.php">Portfolio Single Full Width</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="portfolio_single_options.php">Portfolio Single Options</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="blogoverview_grid.php">Blog</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="aboutme.php">About Me</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                            <!-- end navigation items -->
                        </ul>   
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- end nav -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css to perform that effect of a blue background when active:

```
yourDivId li:active{
background-color: blue;
}

yourDivId li:hover{
background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Using that css you can use JS to change the class to "active" when each li is clicked.

You can see what I mean here:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

Read this:

**Tip:** The **:active** selector can be used on all elements, not only links.

**Tip:** Use the **:link** selector to style links to unvisited pages, the **:visited** selector to style links to visited pages, and the **:hover** selector to style links when you mouse over them.

**Note:** **:active** MUST come after **:hover** (if present) in the CSS definition in order to be effective!

About the JavaScript part you can use this answer on this forum:

```
$('li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

From: [Add & remove active class from a navigation link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379776/add-remove-active-class-from-a-navigation-link)

Answer (score 0):

**first**, i suggest create your nav in separate php file and include it in other file and.

**second**, use javascript code like this:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("**yourMenuItems**").children.item(<?php echo $SelectedMenu; ?>).classList.add("active");
</script>
```

**thired**, when include your nav file set $SelectedMenu variable.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use PHP and this Class to get a basic template system and it also includes a function to add "active" class to menus.

```
<?php
/**
    HOW TO USE THIS CLASS.

    In every page:
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <?php
        require 'Page.php'

        $page = new Page('Home', 1); <-- initialize the page object
        $page->addJS('path/tojs.js'); <-- add javascripts if needed
        $page->addCSS('path/tocss.css') <-- add css if needed
        $page->startBody(); <--- start the page body

    ?>

    --HTML HERE--

    <?php
    $page->endBody(); <--- close the body
    echo $page->render('inc/template.php'); <-- render the template

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**/

class Page {
    private $title, $id = 0, $stylesheets=array(), $javascripts=array(), $body;

    function __construct($title, $id = 0) {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->id = (int)$id;
    }

    function setTitle($title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    function setId($id){
        $this->id = (int)$id;
    }

    function addCSS($path) {
        $this->stylesheets[] = $path;
    }

    function addJS($path) {
        $this->javascripts[] = $path;
    }

    function startBody() {
        ob_start();
    }

    function endBody() {
        $this->body = ob_get_clean();
    }

    function render($path) {
        ob_start();
        require($path);
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    function activeMenu($id){
        echo $this->id == $id ? 'active' : '' ;
    }

    function minifyCSS(){
        $buffer = "";

        foreach ($this->stylesheets as $css) {
            $buffer .= file_get_contents($css);
        }

        $buffer = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $buffer);
        $buffer = str_replace(': ', ':', $buffer);
        $buffer = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $buffer);

        return $buffer;
    }
}
```

Then in the template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title><?php echo $this->title; ?></title>

        <?php
            foreach ($this->stylesheets as $stylesheet) {
                echo '<link href="' . $stylesheet . '" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />' . PHP_EOL;
            }

            //or echo '<style>'.$this->minifyCSS().'</style>'; to get minimized css
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>

        <nav>
            <a href="home.php" class="<?php $this->activeMenu(1) ?>">Home</a>
            <a href="other.php" class="<?php $this->activeMenu(5) ?>">Other Page</a>
        </nav>

        <?php echo $this->body; ?>

        <?php
            foreach ($this->javascripts as $javascript) {
                echo '<script src="' . $javascript . '"></script>' . PHP_EOL;
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```